# Tableau Creating Common Custom Bins for Three Fields

Tags: tableau-api, bucket

I am trying to create a single graph that groups three different measures into buckets. Each of these three measures are a price from one of three sources subtracted from the median of the three sources. I can individually create three graphs to do this but I would like to show them side by side in one graph

I have created three different buckets with IF/THEN/ELSE statements. But I'm having trouble grouping these side by side in the same graph.

Below is an example of 1 bucket. I have three different prices so ideally in this example "Price1" would just be a variable allowing each of the different sources to flow through correctly:

```
IF [Price1-MEDIAN] = 0 
THEN "MEDIAN" 
ELSEIF [Price1-MEDIAN] > 0 and [Price1-MEDIAN] <= .5 
THEN "0-.5" 
ELSEIF [Price1-MEDIAN] >.5 and [Price1-MEDIAN] <=1 
THEN ".5-1" 
ELSEIF [Price1-MEDIAN] >1 and [Price1-MEDIAN] <=2 
THEN "1-2" 
ELSEIF [Price1-MEDIAN] > 2 and [Price1-MEDIAN] <=3 
THEN "2-3" 
Else ">3" 
END
```

Comment: can you attach workbook with dummy data?

Answer (score 0):

You can create three different bins (like you did) and then graph them together with the [Measure Values](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/datafields_understanddatawindow_meavalues.htm) field.

Another approach would be to pivot the data when you bring it in.  This way all of your bins are under a single dimension and you can break them out using the name of the measure.